# Set a certain area of a canvas to be clickable

Tags: java, swing

I need an example of this:
I have a canvas. And it refreshes constantly, I want to make an area of this canvas clickable, like a certain rectangular area of the canvas clickable, but not the whole canvas.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question. " I want there to be a Jbutton on this canvas from an image that when clicked, or hovered upon will change" is not clear to me.

Comment: I have a canvas. And it refreshes constantly, I want to make an area of this canvas clickable, like a certain rectangular area of the canvas clickable, but not the whole canvas.

Comment: Thank you. This is clearer. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What is canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way to do it is to add transparent button, where you want the "background" to be clickable:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class APanel extends JPanel{

    APanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW); //panel color to make it distinct

        //add button
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30)); //use layout manager to place it where you want
        btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);//make btn transparent
        btn.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));//change button cursor
        //optionally : remove border by btn.setBorder(null);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("button pressed !");
            }
        });
        add(btn);   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new APanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ditched the canvas, and just drew it to a panel, and positioned the buttons anywhere on the panel and added an image to the button. Now it looks great! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LayerLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html), which you can add components on top of each other

> A layered pane is a Swing container that provides a third dimension
>   for positioning components: depth, also known as Z order. When adding
>   a component to a layered pane, you specify its depth as an integer.
>   The higher the number, closer the component is to the "top" position
>   within the container. If components overlap, the "closer" components
>   are drawn on top of components at a lower depth. The relationship
>   between components at the same depth is determined by their positions
>   within the depth.